# sync txt file in internal storage with txt file in dropbox dropbox api

Tags: java, android, synchronization, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to sync a txt file in android internal storage (or sdcard for that matter) and have it automatically sync to a txt in my dropbox. i've used dropbox api but don't have hold on on how to achieve this. help needed please.

Update:

Here's my function to get the txt content to LogCat for now:

```
public void getFromDbx(){

        try {
            mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);

            final String TEST_DATA = " Database does not exist yet";

            final String TEST_FILE_NAME = "data.txt";
            DbxPath testPath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, TEST_FILE_NAME);

            // Create DbxFileSystem for synchronized file access.
            DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());

            // Print the contents of the root folder.  This will block until we can
            // sync metadata the first time.

            //dont need this code -- ahmed

            // Create a test file only if it doesn't already exist.
            if (!dbxFs.exists(testPath)) {
                DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.create(testPath);
                try {
                    testFile.writeString(TEST_DATA);
                } finally {
                    testFile.close();
                }

            }

            // Read and print the contents of test file.  Since we're not making
            // any attempt to wait for the latest version, this may print an
            // older cached version.  Use getSyncStatus() and/or a listener to
            // check for a new version.
            if (dbxFs.isFile(testPath)) {
                String resultData;
                DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);
                try {
                    resultData = testFile.readString();
                } finally {
                    testFile.close();
                }

                Log.i("dbx",resultData);
            } else if (dbxFs.isFolder(testPath)) {

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

My OnCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

        //connect dbx to account
                mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);

                //get data from ems_data.txt from dropbox account
                getFromDbx();
```

My OnActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                getFromDbx();
            } else {
                Log.i("dbxems", "Link to Dropbox failed or was cancelled.");
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

My Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testdatabaseactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >

    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testdatabaseactivity.TestDatabaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <instrumentation
            android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
            android:label="your tests label"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.testdatabaseactivity" />

        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testdatabaseactivity.MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testdatabaseactivity.SearchByName"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_by_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="db-KEY_HERE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT: there is no error, the app shows the auth screen, I click allow and then nothing happens. I can press allow 10 times and nothing happens at all..

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't much to go on here. Could you share the code you've written so far and where things have gone wrong?

Comment: @smarx-done, hope that helps you help me :)

Comment: You said you get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Where in your code do you get that exception?

Comment: that was in error, i misread my logcat, there is no error and i've edited the post accordingly. my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getFromDbx`, you call `startLink`, which brings up the UI to link an account. When that succeeds, your `onActivityResult` is executed, where you call `getFromDbx`, which calls `startLink` again. :-) Looks like an infinite loop to me.

Comment: smarx- thanks for your reply. that makes a lot of sense. i took this code from the tutorial sample and that's what was happening there as well. i'll look into it and in the meanwhile du have any edits to the code I can make to make this work? thanks.

Comment: smarx- so I moved the startLink call out of the getFromDbx into oncreate and now the screen doesn't show, but in onActivityResult it goes to 'else' and prints out Link to Dropbox Failed or was cancelled...

Comment: Could you tell me what tutorial you were following? If it has a bug, I want to make sure to fix it.

Comment: Could you update your code in the question to match what you're doing now?

Comment: smarx- thanks for your help. I fixed it by doing what you told me, and then I was missing an important thing: get file info, apparently you need to do that before you getString from a file in dropbox api; thank you so much :)

Comment: basically where I write "don't need this code", apparently I DO need it

Comment: I'm not sure hat you mean by "get file info," but you can read a file from Dropbox without performing any previous operations.

Comment: adding this worked; no idea why. i know i'm a n00b.
`List<DbxFileInfo> infos = dbxFs.listFolder(DbxPath.ROOT);
         //   mTestOutput.setText("\nContents of app folder:\n");
            for (DbxFileInfo info : infos) {
           //     mTestOutput.append("    " + info.path + ", " + info.modifiedTime + '\n');
            }`

Comment: @smarx- can I get file info of a dropbox file from its public link?

Comment: That sounds like a new and unrelated question. Open a new question?

Comment: @smarx- [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596252/get-metadata-from-dropbox-link-without-auth)