# Get Metadata from Dropbox Link Without Auth

Tags: java, android, synchronization, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to check for a version changed/get metadata of a text-file with a shared link on dropbox. I will not be using dropbox api as it makes users use their own accounts. I want them to link to my account and I cannot do that manually since I might change my password later.

so: no auth token, just get metadata from shared link of dropbox so that I can check for version changes and if the version has changed download the contents of the new file.

also: I'm open to other suggestions to make this work as well. Please explain in a little detail your solution.

Updated E-Tag Issue:

```
public void getFromOnlineTxtDatabase(){
        try{
            URL url = new URL("url-here");
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(false);
            con.setReadTimeout(20000);
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            //get etag for update check
                String etag = con.getHeaderField("etag");
            //String etag= "";

            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");
            ((HttpURLConnection) con).setRequestMethod("GET");
            //System.out.println(con.getContentLength()) ;
            con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println(responseCode);
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int chars_read;
            //int total = 0;
            while ((chars_read = in.read()) != -1) 
            {
                char g = (char) chars_read;
                buffer.append(g);
            }
            final String page = buffer.toString();
            //create password_ems.txt to internal
            if (fileExistance("data.txt")){
                File dir = getFilesDir();
                File file = new File(dir, "data.txt");
                boolean deleted = file.delete();
                stringToTxt(page, "data.txt");


            }else{
                stringToTxt(page, "data.txt");
            }

            if (fileExistance("data_etag.txt")){
                File dir = getFilesDir();
                File file = new File(dir, "etag.txt");
                boolean deleted = file.delete();
                stringToTxt(etag, "etag.txt");


            }else{
                //create etag_file
                stringToTxt(etag, "data_etag.txt");
            }

            //  Log.i("Page", page);
        }catch(Exception e){
            showDialog("Database Fetch Failure","Unable to Fetch Password Database, check your internet" +
                    " connection and try again later.",0);
            Log.i("Page", "Error");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do an HTTP `HEAD` request against a public or shared Dropbox URL, you'll get, among other things, an `etag` header. I don't know that this behavior is guaranteed, since I don't think it's documented anywhere, but at least for now the `etag` header can be used to determine when a file has changed. (If the `etag` is different, the file has changed.)

**EDIT**

In general when using ETags, the most efficient thing to do is issue a `GET` request with a header of `If-None-Match: <old etag>`. If the content hasn't changed, this will respond with a 304, but if the content has changed, this will download the new content as per a normal `GET` request (and the response will be 200).

Comment: @smarx- thanks for the answer. do I do the HTTP HEAD request on the dropbox url, where the txt file is 'inside' a dropbox layout, or the url where the browser displays the txt file as pure txt, without any dropbox 'affiliation'. I have both urls.

Comment: The latter. Do this on the link to the actual content.

Comment: @smarx- when I view the source code however it's just text. are you sure the head will work?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to try it than to ask? :-) If you have `curl`, just do `curl -I <url>` and see for yourself.

Comment: @smarx- this is what i have via curl...... 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=0
Content-length: 5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ascii
Date: Tue, 03 Sep 2013 17:42:01 GMT
etag: 18n
pragma: public
Server: nginx
x-dropbox-request-id: fad429064481bf016d9eb7
X-RequestId: 7cd34e34b1f44e44276b3650f
x-server-response-time: 175
Connection: keep-alive
' there is no last modified. is the etag approach 'pretty much' foolproof? thanks.

Comment: @smarx- this is not working, the files dont download at all and function catches exception: `String etag = con.getHeaderField("ETag");`

Comment: ETags are generally used by the browser to request data only if it's changed, so it's pretty safe to rely on the ETag changing any time the content does. (If this doesn't happen, browsers will be incorrectly caching stale data.) As to your code not working, it's hard to guess what's wrong, since you haven't shared the code or the exception. :-) I do notice that you're using the capitalization "ETag," while the Dropbox servers seem to emit "etag" (lowercase). That's possibly a problem.

Comment: hokay: i didn't think the case would be a problem will try again.

Comment: @smarx- updated question with code, turned ETaG into etag... still catching exception. intuitively I'm thinking it's the placement of my etag request. can you see what's wrong? Edit: works fine if I comment out the String etag = .. line.

Comment: I see your updated code. I think the reason that line is failing is because you're trying to read the header before you've even sent the request. :-) Also, you're only doing a `GET` request. I don't see the `HEAD` request at all. You might want to start a new thread to get some general help making a `HEAD` request and reading the response headers. We've strayed pretty far from this question, which was about how you can tell if the content at a Dropbox public link has changed.

Comment: you can answer the get vs. head over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600720/getting-header-info-etag-of-online-txt-file?noredirect=1#comment27377603_18600720) if you want :)

Comment: @smarx- also just one more thing, I'm thinking of getting the etag as string, storing it in an internal storage txt file so that it can be fetched and compared at app startup. you mention if-none-match, how do I use that to compare with the previous etag as an alternative way to match etags

Comment: `If-None-Match` is an HTTP header. You would use the previous ETag as the value of that header when making the `GET` request.

Comment: @smarx- so I need to store the previous etag value somewhere obviously? I can just use String.IsEqual() no?

Comment: What you're planning to do is 1) Fetch the ETag, and then 2) Get the new content if the ETag doesn't match. That's two web requests. What I'm proposing is 1) Ask for the new content with If-None-Match: <old etag>, just a single web request. The server will send you new content if the ETag doesn't match, or it will just reply with 304 (Not Modified) if the ETag matches. But first just try to get something working before trying to optimize. :-)

Comment: so apparently I'm doing GET instead of HEAD, I don't know how to change GET to HEAD, any idea on how to do that? i've looked at a lot of places and can't get it right.