# Get Dropbox public folder's metadata without authentication

Tags: dropbox

I'm about to create a blog and wanted to host the content on Dropbox (only Markdown files, everything else is on my server) because I want to be able to quickly upload and edit posts from all my devices without having to get some FTP app on them.

So far I managed to access files via `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/********/<sub-folder>/<file name>.md` and like pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596252/get-metadata-from-dropbox-link-without-auth) I can get the last-modified attribute via etags.

However, I'm stuck at getting a file list (or a folder's metadata in general). Is this possible *without* using OAuth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible without using the API. But why are you against using the API?

Feel free to use my tool https://dbxoauth2.site44.com/ to get an OAuth access token for your account. Then just do an HTTP GET to `https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/<path>` with an `Authorization` header of `Bearer <token>`. Ditto for getting the actual file contents, just use `/files/auto/<path>` instead.

Oh, unless you're doing this client-side in JavaScript? In that case, this won't work since you can't give your access token out to the client (where it could be abused by anyone who visited your website).

Comment: I refrained from using OAuth because I don't see the reason I need to log in in order to get information which is publicly accessible anyways, but if the API is only available to those using OAuth it can't be helped. (using your app gives me the following error: `Invalid redirect_uri: u'https://dbxoauth2.site44.com'. It must exactly match one of the redirect URIs you've pre-configured for your app (including the path)`) Guess I'll have to take a closer look at the API then.

Comment: As the instructions say, "Be sure to enter `https://dbxoauth2.site44.com` in the 'OAuth 2 redirect URI' field."

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What exactly does your site do? (It works fine btw, thx :)

Comment: It just automates the OAuth 2 flow for you. (It's a substitute for writing your own app that logs a user in.)

Comment: so the generated token will still work in case your site goes down, right?

Comment: Yes. The access token (which you already have) is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

make "Public" folder and go https://www.dropbox.com/enable_public_folder

back to your dropbox folder (web) right mouse at file in public folder and chose "Copy public link..."

---

Update: `As of September 1, 2017 public links have been disabled for all users.`
https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/public-folder